# How can I export data from a .dxr file?

Tags: windows-7, file-format

Does anyone know how to extract data from `.dxr` file ?

I have an old CD which won't work on Windows 7 64-bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the DXR file format is used for Shockwave video. Presumably the [Shockwave player](http://get.adobe.com/shockwave/) can be used to extract some info from it.

Since it is a proprietary format, it may be difficult to find other tools or construct tools to extract information.